# How to generate icons for Xamarin file/ folder structure with two images in each folder

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, icons, image-resizing

The default structure for icons in a Xamarin application for an android app at the moment is:

**folders:**

mipmap-hdpi

mipmap-mdpi

mipmap-xhdpi

mipmap-xxhdpi

mipmap-xxxhdpi

And within each of these folders there are two PNG images that are named:

icon.png

launcher_foreground.png

I have searched for a couple of hours to find some sort of generator that can generate the "launcher_foreground.png" image. All the generators I have seen only generate ONE image in each of these folders.

According to Xamarin, including two images in each of these folders is "good practice" but every generator I have seen does not generate icons this way.
Is there a tool that anyone knows of that can generate each of these images in the format stated above?

If not, is there a way I can use a single SVG file as an icon? Since an SVG file can scale dynamically and has been able to do so for a very long time. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an svg as your app icon because Android doesn't support that, but you can resize your images (svg or png) automatically to the Android, iOS, UWP standard required sizes using [ResizetizerNT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Resizetizer.NT/) package.

1. Download and Install the Nuget Package  in all your projects (shared and native).
2. Add your image to the shared project, and set it build action to "SharedImage" (this build option will only be available after package is installed).
3. In your shared project `.csproj` file, specify the `BaseSize` property for your image:
   It should correspond to the x1 size or in Android the `mdpi` size `48,48` [source](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp) and for the second one `108,108`.

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <SharedImage Include="icon.svg" BaseSize="48" />
  <SharedImage Include="icon.svg" BaseSize="108" Link="launcher_foreground.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

4. Output (resized) images will be found in folder: `obj\[Debug|Release]\100\resizetize\r\`

#### Resources

[Documentation: How to use it](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT#how-to-use-it)

[Author explanation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7a7HKiFypw)

[Official repo](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have not tested it because by the time you answered this question I had downloaded Android Studio, got java WebView to work with the an Angular SPA App I am working on and set up the icons using Android Studios "Image Asset" utility. The APK is now 3MB instead of 18MB(from Xamarin), which is great! I will come back to this answer if I need to get the IOS version running using Xamarin. Thanks